# Google Pub/Sub Middle Ware Rest/API integrations

Tags: rest, google-bigquery, publish-subscribe

Trying to use Pub/Sub as a middleware to stream data for customer consent management, as customer accounts are created, or privacy preferences are updated, we want to stream the data to our Customer Databases. Due to Big Query limits we cannot update directly to the table, so we want to use a pub/sub middleware to manage the updates.

This is the API body/URL we are using, but pub/sub is receiving nulls though when I webhook the data, values populate.

Any thoughts, not sure if its a pub/sub schema issue, or if we are using an incorrect body. We are receiving a 200 message success for this Example

```
   "url": "https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"ProjectName"/topics/"TopicName":publish?
    "body": {
      "messages": [
        {
          "attributes": {
            "email": "Email Address",
            "pc_tokenized_url": "URL String",
            "email_opt_in": "TRUE",
            "customer_id": "############"
          }
        }
      ]
```